# Weird compiler behavior on LeetCode

Tags: c++

I was solving **LeetCode problem**: [7. Reverse Integer](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/), for testing purposes I was printing some values (`long long x2` and `long long x3`). Here, value of `xRough` were assigned to `x2` and `x3` if `x` or `xRough` is negative, otherwise an undefined value will be assined. But, **LeetCode compiler** assigns value of `xRough` to `x2` and `x3` even if `x` is positive (instead of assigning an undefined value). I tested this code on different compilers and they gave undefined values of `x2` and `x3` when `x` is positive. But **LeetCode compiler** is giving the wrong result.

Isn't this wrong or weird behavior of the **LeetCode compiler** or am I missing some point here?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int reverse(int x) {

        long long x2, x3;
        long long xRough = (long long) x;
        
        if (xRough < 0){
            x2 = x3 = (-1) * xRough;
        }
        
        cout<<x2<<" "<<x3<<" "<<xRough<<endl;
        
        return 0;

    }
};
```

I have also got **Accepted** with this weird behavior of compiler. The accepted code is:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int reverse(int x) {

        long long flag = 0, y, x2, x3, xRough = (long long) x;
        long long theNum = 0, i = 1;
        
        if (xRough < 0)
            x2 = x3 = std::abs(xRough);
         
        while (1) {
            x2 = x2 / 10;

            i = i * 10;

            if (x2 == 0)
                break;
        }
        i = i / 10;

        while (1) {
            y = x3 % 10;
            x3 = x3 / 10;

            theNum = theNum + y * i;
            i = i / 10;

            if (x3 == 0)
                break;
        }

        if (x < 0) {
            if (theNum > std::pow(2, 31))
                return 0;
            else
                return (-1) * theNum;
        } else {
            if (theNum > (std::pow(2, 31) - 1))
                return 0;
            else
                return theNum;
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241362/discussion-on-question-by-rawnak-yazdani-weird-compiler-behavior-on-leetcode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int reverse(int x) {

        long long x2, x3;
        long long xRough = (long long) x;
        
        if (xRough < 0){
            x2 = x3 = (-1) * xRough;
        }
        
        cout<<x2<<" "<<x3<<" "<<xRough<<endl;
        
        return 0;

    }
};
```

There are two cases one has to distinguish. Either `xRough < 0` is `true` or it is `false`.

When it is `true` `x2` will get a value assigned and everything works as you expect.

When it is `false` then the code tries to print the values of `x2` and `x3`, but they are not initialized. They have indeterminate values. You cannot do anything with indeterminate values without invoking undefined beahvior.

The only way the function has defined output is when `xRough < 0` is `true`. When it is false the output can be anything. Hence, completely ignoring the case of `xRough < 0` being `false` is allowed for the compiler. Thats what compilers are built for, thats why they are good in optimizing code, they can eliminate paths in the code that are never taken (or may never be taken because the outcome is undefined anyhow).

Comment: But the fact is I got accepted with the undefined behavior of the compiler. What I want is: the compiler should give a compile-time error on this.

Comment: @RawnakYazdani you want to use a different langauge then. C++ does not give you an error for everything that can go wrong. Sometimes compilers can warn about using an uninitialized variable, but not always and not in this case https://godbolt.org/z/znE3hEsrc

Comment: @RawnakYazdani The compiler won't, because the function might have explicitly been defined only to accept negative values – and have been correctly documented as such, which the compiler cannot see! So the compiler always optimises the best it can for paths of which the behaviour is defined, ommitting anything unnecessary, comparable to `unsigned int i = 0; if(i < 0)`

Comment: @Aconcagua But when the program tries to print an undefined variable, it should give a run time error!

Comment: @RawnakYazdani why should it? Thats not how C++ works. There are other languages that try to prevent you from any possible mistake and put this as a prime priority for the language design, but thats not C++

Comment: @RawnakYazdani As a rule, always initialize all variables. Compiler can usually optimize out code that has no effect, and if the initialization code appears to have effect, maybe better have it in...

Comment: @RawnakYazdani consider a different example of derferencing a pointer `int value = *p;`. I don't want the compiler to add expensive code that checks if the pointer is valid. I want efficient code that just does what I want it to do. The checks you want to have are expensive always, they only help in code that is wrong anyhow and don't help in code that is correct

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I just wanted to say this feature can be added to C++, but it is not C++ right now.

Comment: @RawnakYazdani and I try to explain that it is unlikely to be added to C++, while other languages have it

Comment: @RawnakYazdani C++ standard actually already has a concept of "trap value" meaning an illegal value which could cause a CPU "trap". But in real modern processors integers don't have trap values. Every possible bit patterns means a number, so at runtime it is impossible to know if value is random garbage or initialized/calculated valid value. There is no distinction.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is in fact a gcc [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18501). Other compilers do warn about this mistake.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number *'Bug'* is a bit hard a word for behaviour that's actually correct according to the standard... Agree, though, GCC could do a bit better.

Comment: @RawnakYazdani The main paradigma of C++ is *'don't pay for what you don't need'* – and if there's code that is only specified for specific paths it assumes that his has been done deliberately and the paths with undefined behaviour are not used anyway. This paradigma trades safety for efficiency. If you want the latter, C++ is your choice, if you prefer the former better chose another language.

Comment: @Aconcagua According to gcc documentation, the warning should be emitted. There is a specific option to enable it. Bit it doesn't work. It is a bug.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Ah, OK, agree...

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. thats interesting. Nevertheless one shouldnt rely on warnings for UB in general